# htaccess redirect from empty folder to another directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an empty directory at `www.example.com/ar/carprices`.

I would like to redirect all urls from

```
www.example.com/ar/carprices
```

to

```
www.example.com/carprices/ar
```

I have placed the following .htaccess in the `www.example.com/ar/carprices` folder but it does not work:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*)ar/carprices(.*) $1carprices/ar$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Also, there's like a million other "how do i write my rewrite rules" questions that asking another one really seems like you're a little to tired to actually read any of the answers to these questions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I suggest you stop judging people's efforts.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow's core concept is *judging people's efforts*; the even have friggin' *points* to measure the value of someone's effort!

Comment: @MarcusMüller They measure positive efforts. Not stuff like "nah, there 'migh't be millions of questions like this one, this 'might' be just another one". or "Lets just shutdown stackoverflow and go to sleep as all questions 'might' have been asked and we do not need any effort to take new ones"

Comment: No, question points are really meant as an assessment of quality and hence, there's a downvote button for negative feedback (that wouldn't exist otherwise). Have you actually clicked on the [tag:mod-rewrite] tag button and gone through stuff? Anyway, this is not a discussion for comments. If you're interested in discussing this, I'd recommend going to http://meta.stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: @Marcus Müller - yes I have gone through similar question before posting it. And that's what I meant by not judging people's efforts and not just because it "seems" that someone is tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use RedirectMatch here :

```
RedirectMatch ^/ar/carprices/(.*)$ /carprices/ar/$1
```

Will redirect /ar/carprices/ to /carprices/ar

For internal url redirection ,use :

In htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ar/carprices/(.*)$ /carprices/ar/$1 [NC,L]
```

leading slash is not matched in RewriteRule in htaccess context, that is why I remove it from the regex pattern.

Comment: Ok the answer is right, but I was looking for an internal redirect. As in the url in the browser stays the same ' /ar/carprices/' but internally it fetches from '/carprices/ar'